# How do I iterate over adjacent PIC microcontroller registers?

Tags: c, pic

I'm writing an application for a PIC18F45K80 microcontroller. I would like to retrieve bytes from the eight RXB1D registers. According to the datasheet, "Each receive buffer has an array of registers." Also, studying the defines reveals that all 8 registers have consecutive memory addresses, just like an array.

What is the correct syntax for looping through these registers?

I've tried `for (i = 0; i < len; i++) databuf[i] = RXB1D0[i];`, but the compiler returns `error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector`, and points to the RXB1D0 identifier.

Comment: How `RXB1D0` is defined?

Comment: In the IDE library,

`// Register: RXB1D0

#define RXB1D0 RXB1D0

extern volatile unsigned char           RXB1D0              __at(0xF36);`

It's literally a memory address.

Comment: I think @Eugene was asking for you to include the relevant `#define` lines in your question. ... Code in comments is very hard to read.

Comment: Apologies, I hit Enter trying to add a newline to paste the definition, and that posted the incomplete comment. I edited my comment... it seems these comments don't allow newlines.

Comment: Oh, it is using the `__at` extension. Ok, then I'd guess something like `(&RXB1D0)[i]` should work

Comment: you are trying to index a char.  you can't do that. probably need to cast to some sort of pointer.

Comment: Well, it builds... And once my PIC actually comes in the mail, I'll try it out. :) I had a feeling "addressof" would be involved, but I haven't touched C in so long, I wasn't sure how to implement it. Thank you for your help, I'm grateful.

Comment: @4386427 the issue is resolved, the question was answered.

Comment: _Side note:_ It's a criminal felony to use a PIC in a _new_ design in 2022 (vs. 1985)--or at least it _should_ be :-) Even an STM32-like would be comparable/better. Or, a TI MCU. Or, even a Raspberry Pi. Something _without_ banked registers/memory. Something based on Arm (e.g. Cortex-M series). Don't say I didn't warn you ... ;-)

Comment: @CraigEstey `Even an STM32` WHAT? Even? Raspberry Pi does not count as uCs are very **power efficirnt**

Comment: @0___________ The point is that PIC's instruction set and architecture are **terrible**. You said as much in your answer. There was another OP/question that needed low power. This OP didn't state that, but ... There _are_ plenty of very low power MCUs. OP can certainly find one (IIRC, ST is a competitor to microchip and has plenty of low power STM32L*). And, TI does also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would discourage you from doing it this way as PICs use Hardware architecture and memory access via a pointer in some areas might not work as it requires special assembly instructions. They are only 8 so I would do it this way:

```
#define GETREG(b, i) (b)[i] = RXB1D ## i
#define GETREGS(b) do {GETREG(b,0);GETREG(b,1);GETREG(b,2);GETREG(b,3);\
                       GETREG(b,4);GETREG(b,5);GETREG(b,6);GETREG(b,7);}while(0)
```

and usage:

```
void foo()
{
    char databuff[8];
    GETREGS(databuff);
}
```

Every read will compile to two assembly instructions. Even if you find the way of looping using pointers it will result in much more instructions.